# Map not displayed in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, maps, jupyter-notebook, geopandas

I am on a very basic coding level, and was trying to create a map to present the variations of car ownership in London, however when I run the code (the exact same one I've used before but for another data frame) the notebook shows the axes and the legend but not the map itself.

This is the code:

```
df2010 = pd.read_csv('Licensed_vehicles_2010.csv')
sort_df = df_lsoa.sort_values(by='LAD11NM', ascending=False)
merge_df = pd.merge(sort_df, df2010, how = 'left', on = 'LAD11NM')
gdf=gpd.GeoDataFrame(merge_df)
gdf.plot(column='Cars', legend=True, cmap='OrRd')
plt.show()
```

However, all I get is:
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgBC5.png)

And I cannot figure out why this particular map is not displayed, while I used the same code for data from 2017 and it worked perfectly.

Thanks!

Comment: have you checked the file

Comment: Yes, it is not corrupted in any way, taken from the same excel file and has the same data variables

Comment: You probably didn't properly set geometry column. You are not getting any AttributeError? Try `gdf.geometry.name`, what you'll get? You might need to specify geometry column when defining geodataframe or use `.set_geometry()` after that. But I would have to see the structure of your dataframes.

Comment: To check if there is a valid geometry in first row (index=0), you can write the code as `gdf.loc[0, 'geometry'].